# Update JTable with Separate Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable, runnable

The purpose of the application is to query a table, and take that information and update a JTable.  Right now the ThreadTask() is able to query the table and obtain the information.  My question is how do I update the JTable GUI object with the information obtained from the database?

```
    public class AdminManager extends JFrame {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        AdminManager frame = new AdminManager();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            // Setup connection pool

            ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ThreadTask(connection), 2000, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */
        public AdminManager() {
            // Setup GUI

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model.addColumn("#");


            tableQueue = new JTable(model);
            tableQueue.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(3);
            scrollPane.setViewportView(tableQueue);

        }
    class updateTable extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{order_num});
            return null;
        }

    }
}
class grabData implements Runnable {
    private Connection connection;
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private String order_num;

    public grabData(Connection c, DefaultTableModel m) {
         connection = c;
         model = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Working ... ");
       String sql = "SELECT * FROM order_queue;";
       Statement st;
       try {
           st = connection.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                order_num = rs.getString("order_num");
                System.out.println(order_num);
                updateTable.execute()
            }
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }   
   }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are adding rows to a TableModel object that is held by a visualized JTable, then you must do so on the Swing event thread, the EDT. If you're creating a completely new TableModel one that isn't visualized, then I think it is safe to fill it off of the EDT, and then set it as the JTable's model *on* the EDT.

One consideration, if you want to add rows the JTable as they become available, consider using a `SwingWorker<Void, RowObject>`, and then pass the RowObject obtained in the `while (rs.next()) {` via a publish/process method pair.

**Edit:**
You could just skip the SwingWorker and just queue up adding the table's row on the EDT:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    final String order_num = rs.getString("order_num");
    // System.out.println(order_num);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{order_num});
      }      
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes I will be adding rows to a table that has already been created.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how it would be setup?

Comment: +1 for SwingWorker. @scriptdiddy: The `SwingWorker` API includes an example of updating a `TableModel`.

Comment: How would I call the SwingWorker class from outside of my main class.. for example calling it from inside the ThreadTask class?

Comment: @scriptdiddy: The SwingWorker does not have to be called from the Swing event thread, and you would call `execute()` on it to have it run. It will run on a thread that is background to the thread that called it. But also note that you're not required to use a SwingWorker as long as you load thing into the JTable on the event thread.

Comment: I updated my code above to include the swing worker.  How can I execute it from within the grabData class?

Comment: @scriptdiddy: your SwingWorker is wrong in that you're calling in the doInBackground portion that which should be performed on the EDT -- the exact opposite of what should be done!

Comment: yeah I didn't think that was right.  Eclipse forced me to included that or put abstract in front of the class

Comment: Hovercraft now I see what you are saying... I'm sorry I was a bit confused.  I'm still having trouble with passing the object into the thread.. for example I added public grabData(Connection c, DefaultTableModel m) for including the table model to add it. is this how I should do it?  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @script: yes, that could work, as long as the table model is a valid object when the method is called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13588/discussion-between-scriptdiddy-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)